# Font Size in Plot Legends

Tags: code-request, legending

How can I change the font size of the Legend? I have to plot 5 functions, and I already wrote the code, with the colors and so on.

But when I write the final code for the PlotLegends, that is

```
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[{Style["\[Nu] = 0", Black, 10], ["\[Nu]=0.25", Red, 
10],["\[Nu]=0.5", Green, 10] AND SO ON }, {0.2, 0.7}]
```

It doesn't work.

I want to change the plot legend size, in order to have a better plot.

Comment: You didn't give code other people can run, so try this: `Plot[Table[ChebyshevT[k, x], {k, 1, 3}] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[MapThread[Style, {{"k = 1", "k = 2", "k = 3"}, {Black, Red, Green}}], LabelStyle -> 10], {0.25, 0.65}]]`

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. That works perfectly! Just one more question: how to change the font? Say I want to use Times New Roman, or Serif...

Comment: Just modify the `LabelStyle` setting: `LabelStyle -> {10, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}`. Please read the docs for `LineLegend[]`, it's all there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LineLegend` is the function that ultimately constructs the legend for `Plot`.  It has a lot of options that can be modified to adjust the appearance of the legend.  If you're trying to control the size, the most useful options are probably

- `LabelStyle`: change the overall style for the labels, including font size
- `LegendMarkerSize`: control how long the sample lines are
- `LegendMargins`: control how much space is left around the legend
- `LegendLayout`: switch from column to row

Here are some examples of each of these options being used:

```
{Framed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"}]],
 Framed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"}, 
   LabelStyle -> 10]],
 Framed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 5]],
 Framed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"}, 
   LegendMargins -> 0]],
 Framed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"}, 
   LegendLayout -> "Row"]]}
```

[image]

Individually they may not be much smaller, but using them together can have a much bigger effect.

```
Framed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"},
    LabelStyle -> 10, LegendMarkerSize -> 5, LegendMargins -> 0]]
```

[image]